# Apache virtual host not working points to main DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Apache virtual host is not working always points to main DocumentRoot default apache page

The default Document root in my centos server /var/www/html/

I have created a virtual host and have name its as demo.example.com

the virtual host config is

```
<VirtualHost 172.56.12.85:80>
ServerAdmin dev@locahost.com
ServerName demo.exmaple.com
ServerAlias www.demo.example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/demo_product"
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorLog /var/www/html/demo_product/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/demo_product/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: You've a typo in the ServerName. It's exmaple, rather than example. Is that the issue or just a typo when you submitted this question?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following before the VirtualHost section:

```
NameVirtualHost 52.78.89.56:80
```

Comment: Is your apache instance bound to ip 52.78.89.56? Can you confirm with netstat?
For example: netstat -an | grep :80

Comment: Hi @Missaka Wijekoon it reports my private ip 172.31.28.185:80 so I tried configuring it by my private ip <VirtualHost 172.31.28.185:80> the virtual host works but the Main document root is forgotten ...all the folders inside the /var/www/html is not seen at all

Comment: Hi @Danny, I think you should look at the Apache documents and create named virtual hosts based on names.  Please look at the following document: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

BTW, it also appears that your internal ips's may be subject to change.  If so, try to use "*:80" in your <VirtualHost> sections.